# UPDATE query doesn't work on a scheduled job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent-job

I have written this query to update my database.

```
UPDATE SMGCARTES
SET scr_flspedito = '1'
    , scr_dtmodifica = dt_conf
FROM (
    SELECT scr_flspedito
        , scr_codsoc societa
        , scr_numcartone cartone
        , scr_numordine num_ordine_ss
        , ordine num_ordine_px
        , DATA_CONF AS dt_conf
    FROM SMGCARTES A
    LEFT JOIN SMGBOLTES
        ON a.scr_numordine = bll_numordine
            AND a.scr_codsoc = bll_codsoc
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT CASE ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', "Riferimento Spedizione", 1) - 1, - 1), len("Riferimento Spedizione"))
                WHEN len("Riferimento Spedizione")
                    THEN "Riferimento Spedizione"
                ELSE SUBSTRING("Riferimento Spedizione", 1, CHARINDEX('/', "Riferimento Spedizione", 1) - 1)
                END AS ordine
            , "Data consegna prevista" AS cons_prev
            , "Data Conferimento Hub" AS DATA_CONF
        FROM IMPORT_PALLEX
        WHERE "Riferimento Spedizione" IS NOT NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DISTINCT CASE ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', "Riferimento Cliente", 1) - 1, - 1), len("Riferimento Cliente"))
                WHEN len("Riferimento Cliente")
                    THEN "Riferimento Cliente"
                ELSE SUBSTRING("Riferimento Cliente", 1, CHARINDEX('/', "Riferimento Cliente", 1) - 1)
                END AS ordine
            , "Data consegna prevista" AS cons_prev
            , "Data Conferimento Hub" AS DATA_CONF
        FROM IMPORT_PALLEX
        WHERE "Riferimento Spedizione" IS NOT NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DISTINCT CASE ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', "Riferimento Spedizione", 1) - 1, - 1), len("Riferimento Spedizione"))
                WHEN len("Riferimento Spedizione")
                    THEN "Riferimento Spedizione"
                ELSE SUBSTRING("Riferimento Spedizione", CHARINDEX('/', "Riferimento Spedizione", 1) + 1, LEN("Riferimento Spedizione"))
                END AS ordine
            , "Data consegna prevista" AS cons_prev
            , "Data Conferimento Hub" AS DATA_CONF
        FROM IMPORT_PALLEX
        WHERE "Riferimento Spedizione" IS NOT NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DISTINCT CASE ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', "Riferimento Cliente", 1) - 1, - 1), len("Riferimento Cliente"))
                WHEN len("Riferimento Cliente")
                    THEN "Riferimento Cliente"
                ELSE SUBSTRING("Riferimento Cliente", CHARINDEX('/', "Riferimento Cliente", 1) + 1, LEN("Riferimento Cliente"))
                END AS ordine
            , "Data consegna prevista" AS cons_prev
            , "Data Conferimento Hub" AS DATA_CONF
        FROM IMPORT_PALLEX
        WHERE "Riferimento Spedizione" IS NOT NULL
        ) B
        ON a.scr_numordine = ordine
            OR a.scr_numordine = '00' + ordine
            OR ordine = bll_numbolla
    WHERE a.scr_numordine IS NOT NULL
        AND (
            scr_flspedito = '0'
            OR scr_dtmodifica IS NULL
            )
    ) C
WHERE scr_numordine = num_ordine_ss
    AND scr_codsoc = societa
```

When i run the query from sql server manually it works, but when i put it into a scheduled job, the server give me an error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 536).  The step failed.

I've seen that this error is when you are not using the CHARINDEX in the correct way, but when i run the query manually it works!

can anyone help me?

PROBLEM SOLVED!!! i added 2 cursors to the query and i put the value in the cursor... it works perfectly!!! but i don't know why!!!!

Anyone??

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: permissions/security. Are you running the scheduled job under a (more restricted) user account?

Comment: There is no chance we can possibly debug this without a mountain of more information. And the amount of information required makes this a far bigger topic than an online forum. Nothing jumps out at me as being a problem in code because this is going to be data related. You may have to start by removing a number of the unioned queries to isolate which one(s) are causing the issue.

Comment: No, my user can do everything... i've done hundreds of jobs...but this doesn't work

Comment: Hi sean! i've done it... and every single part works perfectly...i can't get out of this...

Comment: For example... i've tried with only one part of the query but it doesn't work when i put it in a scheduled job....

Comment: Try breaking into 4 statements and testing that way.  You may find that your first part of the union is close to perfect - the 2 3 4 parts need to look more like the 1st part.   That would be a join to SMGCARTES.    Instead of creating "table" C try joining though SMGCARTES.